# Unix sudo pry does not start

Tags: ruby, unix

I'm Ubuntu 15.10. I need to run `pry` (pry is alternative irb for Ruby) with root rights.  I've got strange situation, and I do not know how to explain it. `sudo` works, `pry` works, but sudo can not run pry! log below:

```
kvokka@kvokka-PC  ~  sudo pry                                             ✓  4428  12:50:13 
[sudo] password for kvokka: 
sudo: pry: command not found
 kvokka@kvokka-PC  ~  pry                                                1 ↵  4429  12:50:20 
[1] pry(main)> 
 kvokka@kvokka-PC  ~  sudo                                                 ✓  4430  12:50:29 
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
usage: sudo -l [-AknS] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-U user] [-u user] [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
            [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C num] [-g group] [-h host] [-p prompt] [-u user]
            file ...
 kvokka@kvokka-PC  ~  sudo apt-get update                                1 ↵  4431  12:50:50 
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg                                                       
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com wily-security InRelease [65,9 kB]                                
Hit http://archive.canonical.com vivid InRelease                                                  
Hit http://es.archive.ubuntu.com wily InRelease                                                   
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release 
...
```

I use `rbenv` as ruby version manager, `rbenv rehash` did not helps

**UPDATE**

I've found the cause. I run `sudo -i` and `gem list` and saw, that `pry` was not installed in sudo enviroment. do `gem install pry` there. And now it works :)

Comment: How about `sudo ruby -v`?

Comment: Mike, Thank you for helping others by adding your solution.  On SO, it's customary for the answer to be posted as an answer (yes, you may answer your own question).  If you could add your update as a proper answer and then remove it from your question, that would be good.  You will even be able to give your self-answer the checkmark (after a delay), which will help others.

Comment: I saw, that it is regular practice, because I've had few questions, where I've made answers as answers (not updating post) and then got minuses to the question (I've got it 2 times). So, better way I'll print the answer in question body update section. I understand, that it is less pretty, but I need my SO points. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Check where pry is defined

```
which pry
```

then add it to the `PATH` variable of user `root`, or add a symlink in `/usr/bin` which is usually available for all users:

```
sudo ln -s [result of which pry] /usr/bin/pry
```

Comment: Do you still get `sudo: pry: command not found` after these steps?

Comment: I've updated the question. I found the solution. sudo has own gem list, so you need to install gem there, or globally (maybe).